# Php mailer working with utf-8 locally but not on host

Tags: php

I know that has similar posts but nothing help with my problem,
Trying to create a contact form with PHPMailer but when i try to send with greek characters i getting symbols, I noticed that the problem occurs only on Host , when im and i get correct Greek characters.
i tried to set utf-8 but nothing, i tried with encode,decode command also always getting symbols like

```
Î•Î´Ï‰ ÎµÎ¹Î½Î±Î¹ ÎµÎ½Î± Ï€Î±ÏÎ±Î´ÎµÎ¹Î³Î¼Î±

-- Î§ÏÎ·ÏƒÏ„Î¿Ï‚
-- myemail
```

above is the two files of settings.

```
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = // Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Message from website '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Subject line for emails
    
    $host           =  // Your SMTP server. For example, smtp.mail.yahoo.com
    $username       = "yourmail"; //For example, your.email@yahoo.com
    $password       =  // Your password
    $SMTPSecure     = "ssl"; // For example, ssl
    $port           = 993; // For example, 465
    
    
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    
        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));
        
        die($output);
    } 
    
    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    $user_Message = str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    $user_Message = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    
    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    
    //proceed with PHP email.
    include("php/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); //you have to upload class files "class.phpmailer.php" and "class.smtp.php"
 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    
    $mail->Host = $host;
    $mail->Username = $username;
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = $SMTPSecure;
    $mail->Port = $port;

     
    $mail->setFrom($username);
    $mail->addReplyTo($user_Email);
     
    $mail->AddAddress($to_Email);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $user_Message. "\r\n\n"  .'Name: '.$user_Name. "\r\n" .'Email: '.$user_Email;
    $mail->WordWrap = 200;
    $mail->IsHTML(false);

    if(!$mail->send()) {

        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo));
        die($output);

    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .'! Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
    
}
```

And the settings that get the email is above:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "myemail"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Message from website '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Subject line for emails
    
    
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    
        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));
        
        die($output);
    } 
    
    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    $user_Message = str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    $user_Message = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    
    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }
    
    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  
    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message . "\r\n\n"  .'-- '.$user_Name. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Email, $headers);


    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .'! Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the _input data_ this script works with, received in correct UTF-8 encoding? (That would primarily depend on the character encoding of the page that contained the form.)

Comment: @CBroe On page i have on meta  <meta charset="utf-8"> And also in form i have->
   <form class="form contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"  id="contact_form">

Comment: Character encoding specified via HTTP has a higher priority, than via meta element. Check what `default_charset` is set to in the PHP configuration on the system where it doesn’t work.

Comment: @CBroe I search deeper on file class.phpmailer.php i see that has  public $CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; instead of utf-8 i changed but nothing...

Comment: Nah, you did overwrite that with `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` already. I am talking about https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset

Comment: Also im trying to edit that -> $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message . "\r\n\n"  .'-- '.mb_detect_encoding($user_Name, "UTF-8"). "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Email, $headers);

And i get as message : UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set charset on .htaccess and worked !!